# Make a beautiful report on latex from R

Tags: r, latex, sweave, xtable

I would like to produce a `latex` report with `R` code.
I know that the subject has already been discussed many times, and I get lost between `xtable`, `Hmisc`, and packages like `stargazer` or `reporttools`.

I have a database containing about thirty variables (quantitative and qualitative), as well as a variable X (on the example TMA yes / no).
I would like to produce a table containing the summary of each variable, the summary of the variable according to the binary variable X, as well as the appropriate test according to the variable X (Student's test for the quantitative variables and Fisher's for the  qualitative variables).

At the end, I'll get this:

[image]

Below a code for the example:

```
AAA = matrix (data = c (rnorm (10), round (runif (10, min = 1, max = 3), digits = 0), rbinom (10,1,0.5)), nrow = 10, byrow = F)
AAA = as.data.frame (AAA); AAA $ V2 = as.factor (AAA $ V2)
```

It's been a week since I struggled to find a solution!

I will be grateful for the slightest help.

Comment: I would opt for the `knitr` package. It probably has a steeper learning curve, but is much more flexible.

Comment: Do you want to create `R` code that produces exactly this table, or would code that produces the relevant statistics in a preliminary form be enough? Although `xtable` provides a broad range of options, I'm unsure whether things like sub headlines could be achieved.

Comment: I don't need to produce exactly this table, any code that would produces something similar would be great.

Comment: If you want a quick way than try with https://www.tablesgenerator.com/. You can also generate the code using the mentioned link.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I was using tablesgenerator.com before! This time, i wanted something more "professional".

Comment: Maybe `kableExtra` could help. Take a look at the [table page 18 here](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf). It could inspire you. But not so easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the tableone package to create a `TableOne` object and `kable` from the knitr package to create latex.

```
library(tableone)
library(knitr)

example(CreateTableOne)
p <- print(tableOne, printToggle = FALSE, noSpaces = TRUE)
kable(p, format = "latex")
```

giving:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
\hline
  & 1 & 2 & p & test\\
\hline
n & 158 & 154 &  & \\
\hline
time (mean (sd)) & 2015.62 (1094.12) & 1996.86 (1155.93) & 0.883 & \\
\hline
status (\%) &  &  & 0.894 & \\
\hline
0 & 83 (52.5) & 85 (55.2) &  & \\
\hline
1 & 10 (6.3) & 9 (5.8) &  & \\
\hline
2 & 65 (41.1) & 60 (39.0) &  & \\
\hline
age (mean (sd)) & 51.42 (11.01) & 48.58 (9.96) & 0.018 & \\
\hline
sex = f (\%) & 137 (86.7) & 139 (90.3) & 0.421 & \\
\hline
ascites = 1 (\%) & 14 (8.9) & 10 (6.5) & 0.567 & \\
\hline
hepato = 1 (\%) & 73 (46.2) & 87 (56.5) & 0.088 & \\
\hline
spiders = 1 (\%) & 45 (28.5) & 45 (29.2) & 0.985 & \\
\hline
edema (\%) &  &  & 0.877 & \\
\hline
0 & 132 (83.5) & 131 (85.1) &  & \\
\hline
0.5 & 16 (10.1) & 13 (8.4) &  & \\
\hline
1 & 10 (6.3) & 10 (6.5) &  & \\
\hline
bili (mean (sd)) & 2.87 (3.63) & 3.65 (5.28) & 0.131 & \\
\hline
chol (mean (sd)) & 365.01 (209.54) & 373.88 (252.48) & 0.748 & \\
\hline
albumin (mean (sd)) & 3.52 (0.44) & 3.52 (0.40) & 0.874 & \\
\hline
copper (mean (sd)) & 97.64 (90.59) & 97.65 (80.49) & 0.999 & \\
\hline
alk.phos (mean (sd)) & 2021.30 (2183.44) & 1943.01 (2101.69) & 0.747 & \\
\hline
ast (mean (sd)) & 120.21 (54.52) & 124.97 (58.93) & 0.460 & \\
\hline
trig (mean (sd)) & 124.14 (71.54) & 125.25 (58.52) & 0.886 & \\
\hline
platelet (mean (sd)) & 258.75 (100.32) & 265.20 (90.73) & 0.555 & \\
\hline
protime (mean (sd)) & 10.65 (0.85) & 10.80 (1.14) & 0.197 & \\
\hline
stage (\%) &  &  & 0.201 & \\
\hline
1 & 12 (7.6) & 4 (2.6) &  & \\
\hline
2 & 35 (22.2) & 32 (20.8) &  & \\
\hline
3 & 56 (35.4) & 64 (41.6) &  & \\
\hline
4 & 55 (34.8) & 54 (35.1) &  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried it on my data, it seems giving what I needed:-)  In the meantime, I have written a long and non-flexible function that gives roughly the same result ...

Comment: Not sure if the name has changed. But now there is no "tableOne" package (on CRAN) - it's the "tableone" package. https://cran.r-project.org/package=tableone

Comment: I don't know if  that was just an error or if something changed but I have changed it to tableone and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is adding to G.Grothendieck's answer - There is now the `kableExtra` package which offers great functionality to layout tables, in particular themes.

The plain latex output with horizontal and vertical rules will be no more.

[see this vignette for all options](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf)

```
library(tableone)
library(kableExtra)

# directly with a the tableone wrapper for the kable function
kableone(tableOne, booktabs = TRUE, format = "latex")

# or, to give more flexibility for the tableOne object, print first 
# E.g., if you want to use labels for your rows. 
p <- print(tableOne)
kbl(p, booktabs = TRUE, format = "latex")
```

Output

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{lllll}
\toprule
& 1 & 2 & p & test\\
\midrule
n & 158 & 154 &  & \\
time (mean (SD)) & 2015.62 (1094.12) & 1996.86 (1155.93) & 0.883 & \\
status (\%) &  &  & 0.894 & \\
0 & 83 (52.5) & 85 (55.2) &  & \\
1 & 10 ( 6.3) & 9 ( 5.8) &  & \\
\addlinespace
2 & 65 (41.1) & 60 (39.0) &  & \\
age (mean (SD)) & 51.42 (11.01) & 48.58 (9.96) & 0.018 & \\
sex = f (\%) & 137 (86.7) & 139 (90.3) & 0.421 & \\
ascites = 1 (\%) & 14 ( 8.9) & 10 ( 6.5) & 0.567 & \\
hepato = 1 (\%) & 73 (46.2) & 87 (56.5) & 0.088 & \\
\addlinespace
spiders = 1 (\%) & 45 (28.5) & 45 (29.2) & 0.985 & \\
edema (\%) &  &  & 0.877 & \\
0 & 132 (83.5) & 131 (85.1) &  & \\
0.5 & 16 (10.1) & 13 ( 8.4) &  & \\
1 & 10 ( 6.3) & 10 ( 6.5) &  & \\
\addlinespace
bili (mean (SD)) & 2.87 (3.63) & 3.65 (5.28) & 0.131 & \\
chol (mean (SD)) & 365.01 (209.54) & 373.88 (252.48) & 0.748 & \\
albumin (mean (SD)) & 3.52 (0.44) & 3.52 (0.40) & 0.874 & \\
copper (mean (SD)) & 97.64 (90.59) & 97.65 (80.49) & 0.999 & \\
alk.phos (mean (SD)) & 2021.30 (2183.44) & 1943.01 (2101.69) & 0.747 & \\
\addlinespace
ast (mean (SD)) & 120.21 (54.52) & 124.97 (58.93) & 0.460 & \\
trig (mean (SD)) & 124.14 (71.54) & 125.25 (58.52) & 0.886 & \\
platelet (mean (SD)) & 258.75 (100.32) & 265.20 (90.73) & 0.555 & \\
protime (mean (SD)) & 10.65 (0.85) & 10.80 (1.14) & 0.197 & \\
stage (\%) &  &  & 0.201 & \\
\addlinespace
1 & 12 ( 7.6) & 4 ( 2.6) &  & \\
2 & 35 (22.2) & 32 (20.8) &  & \\
3 & 56 (35.4) & 64 (41.6) &  & \\
4 & 55 (34.8) & 54 (35.1) &  & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```